# Lost desktop Icons Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: icons

Is there a specific reason why I would lose an APT desktop icon on Ubuntu 20.04 - After boot today, Clementine was still on the desktop but with no icon. I fixed it by deleting that desktop item and merely added it back, but why did it drop off in the first place? - this has somewhat happened before with clementine where the "fruit" icon changes to a white icon with a gear in it, ie, prior to the "allow launching"form, however, it would launch.

Comment: Is it happening again and again? If it is not reproducible we cannot debug it.

Comment: the snap version or apt version? I have the apt version which works fine and places an icon in the system tray v20.04.3 LTS Please [edit] your question accordingly

Comment: I have edited my original question.